# Is there a i18n/translation solution for Smarty?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, smarty, smarty3

I'm developing a PHP-based application that requires internationalization (i18n) support.

I'm using Smarty 3 as a template solution (and TinyMVC as the framework), and although I've been using it for small projects before (back in the days of Smarty 2.x), I haven't known about any easy-to-use i18n plugins for it. Is there such plugin/extension for Smarty 3.x that'll do the job for me? I don't mind if the backend is a bit hard to setup, that's fine, all I need is a good way to implement it in templates.

I need to translate this app into multiple languages, so I need to find a way for Smarty to support it. Is there one? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`gettext`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) plugin with Smarty, such as the one posted on [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/smarty-developers/browse_thread/thread/d5dcc39589484b0d?pli=1) which the poster developed for Smarty 3 and that he claims to have been using in production for over six months without issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try right now and wait for a few more answers before I accept this, if you don't mind. That plugin lacks a little bit of documentation, though, but I think I'll figure it out. Now onto learning gettext! Haha.